# is it possible to Create SSH Forwarding in the establlished tunnel from server-side

Tags: ssh

Let's assume we have two hosts, HOST-A is SSH client and HOST-B is SSH Server.

Host-A have already established a ssh tunnel to  HOST-B.

if it possible to create Local/remote forwarding on-demond in the established ssh tunnel, from Host-B?

or any way could I get the shell of Host-A from the Host-B?

thank you!!